# Wordpress double post name distinguish by term

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, htaccess, terms

I am working on a store locating Wordpress template where I have 5 categories for services. In each category I have 500 cities. I have rewritten my url from:

```
http://www.website.com/post-type/post
```

to:

```
http://www.website.com/post-type/term-name/post
```

So for example I have in 3 categories the city London, but now Wordpress sees it as double posts and set the url post slug to /post-2

```
http://www.website.com/filter/bikram-yoga/london/
http://www.website.com/filter/kundalini-yoga/london-2/
http://www.website.com/filter/pregnancy-yoga/london-3/
```

etc. etc.

My question is: Is there a way to rewrite the url without the -2 etc. behind it and Wordpress still sees the posts as different post, so distinguish by term?

Comment: It looks like you're misusing taxonomies and post types. If you've created a post type called filter you need to reconsider wether you should actually have created a custom taxonomy called filter instead.

Comment: I recommend you instead setup 2 taxonomies, location, and type, and ask how you would create a URL such as: /filter/type/location This would also give you URLs and archives for type only, and location only listings. Also what if a store is located in more than one category? Also your URL schema now has multiple URLs, which should it pick? How would that be cached? How will you explain Google penalising you for content duplication?

Comment: @kraftner Thanks for sharing the post, the article advices it against.

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for your answer! /filter is just a name that we have chosen. I use /filter to show categories on, /filter/kundalini-yoga to show cities (as posts) and on the city posts is show posts from my post type 'companies' with the Posts 2 Posts http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/ plugin. So it is not a normal Wordpress setting. Also it is not duplicated content for Google because /kundalini-yoga/london and /bikram-yoga/london are certainly different url's

Comment: it's not the URLs that google sees as duplicates, it's the content on those pages. You don't want to have posts that can have lots of different URLs

Comment: No because the content in this case is always unique because we use posts 2 posts to show companies in the neighborhood of London who can do for example Bikram Yoga, and on the other page who can do Kundalini Yoga.